# Verificar se registro já existe em DB Grid Delphi

Tags: delphi, grid

Boa tarde, pessoal.
A linguagem que estou utilizando é Delphi 4.
Estou com uma dúvida em como verificar se um registro já existe em DB Grid.
Os valores que desejo inserir no DBGrid vão ser digitados em um DB Edit.
A tabela possui duas chaves primárias. Caso o conjunto das chaves primárias seja igual a algum registro do banco, o sistema vai impedir a inserção do registro no DBGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tiver uma chave primária, o banco de dados impedirá que você insira essa chave novamente, e o aplicativo lançará um erro "Violação de chave primária", se você realmente quiser pesquisar na tabela quando o usuário digitar a chave no `TEdit`, então você precisará escrever o código no manipulador de eventos `OnChange` da edição usando a função [Locate()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Locate).
A propósito, a procura está no TDataSet não no componente TDBGrid

Comment: Olá, Sami. Eu utilizei o Dataset para resolver esse problema. Obrigado.